# Is Mars visible from naked-eye from Michigan (47N, 88W) these days?

Tags: planet, mars

Is Mars visible at night sky of Michigan these days?

I was trying to search for Mars from Michigan (at elevation of 30 deg and azimuth of 220 deg) around 11:45 PM with binoculars of 20x60 but didn't get successful.

Comment: This sort of time-specific question is not what this site is intended for; however I will try to give you an answer...

Comment: I know, but could get a better forum to ask.

Comment: Install Stellarium on your PC, and configure it for your geographic region (choose the nearest city). Then it will give you a live map of the sky with all the interesting objects you could possibly want to observe.

Comment: Its great app. Thx

Comment: Why do you keep typing MARS in all caps? It is not an acronym - it is Mars.

Comment: @FlorinAndrei are you you referring to http://www.stellarium.org/ if yes then it just gives the representational not the real.So how can you call it as live

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On 16 June 2014 at 11:45pm, it was up not far from 220az 30alt. It was actually 232az, 27alt, almost level and to the right of Spica. It would have been easily seen without binoculars being -0.2 visual magnitude.

You can answer this sort of question yourself by getting a planetarium app like Stellarium, The Sky X, Sky Safari, or one of many others.

Comment: Would you please let me know that, how big MARS can be, in comparison to moon or north star.

Comment: @kaka The North Star is a star, and therefore it always looks like a simple dot, even in a telescope. The Moon - you know how big that is; it's about 30 arcmin, or 1/2 degree of arc. Mars varies a lot in size; sometimes it's closer to Earth, other times it's far away. At the greatest distance, it's as small as 3.5 arcsec; at the closest, it is 25 arcsec; in any case, to the naked eye it always appears as a mere dot; you need a telescope to resolve the actual disk. Currently it's 10 arcsec and decreasing. We had a good observational season recently, when it looked good in a backyard telescope.

Comment: @FlorinAndrei thanks for very terse and precise answer.

Comment: I saw yesterday both MARS and Saturn in south at 220Az, 35El and 180Az, 25El respectively, at 10: 45 pm, 17 June 2014 :)

Comment: I would definitely say so. It is quite visible from South Carolina. it should a little to the south for you around 10 pm I'm guessing. It's pretty much right over my head here.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is. Mars is bright (-0.14 magnitude) and is in the constellation Virgo. It's the brightest star in this region of the sky (SW during the evening) and should appear as a very bright reddish star at a good altitude.

If you need a guide, try to find Leo (W). Virgo is at the left of the constellation.